# Cambiar valor de Required segun condicion

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, class, required

Quisiera saber como puedo modificar la propiedad idIndustria a Required solo si la propiedad operacion tiene como valor un 1.

Esta es la clase de mis propiedades:
public class IndustriasRequestDTO
    {
        public int idIndustria {get; set;}

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese que tipo de accion va a ejecutar")]
    public int opercaion { get; set; }

    public string tipoIndustria { get; set; }
    public DateTime fechaCreacion { get; set; }
    public bool vanderaEliminacion { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente como tiene definido el campo idIndustria siempre tendrá un valor debido a que int no es nullable, así no lo asigne tendrá el valor por defecto de 0.

A continuación adjunto el código con el ajuste para el validador Required en el campo idIndustria.

```
public class IndustriasRequestDTO
{
    [RequiredIdIndustria("opercaion", "1", ErrorMessage = "idIndustria es requerido")]
    public int? idIndustria { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ingrese que tipo de accion va a ejecutar")]
    public int opercaion { get; set; }

    public string tipoIndustria { get; set; }
    public DateTime fechaCreacion { get; set; }
    public bool vanderaEliminacion { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class RequiredIdIndustria : RequiredAttribute
{
    private String NombrePropiedad { get; set; }
    private Object ValorPropiedad { get; set; }

    //Constructor
    //[RequiredIdIndustria("opercaion", "1", ErrorMessage = "idIndustria es requerido")]
    public RequiredIdIndustria(String nombrePropiedad, Object valor)
    {
        NombrePropiedad = nombrePropiedad;
        ValorPropiedad = valor;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object idIndustria, ValidationContext context)
    {
        Object obj = context.ObjectInstance;
        Type tipo = obj.GetType();
        Object valor = tipo.GetProperty(NombrePropiedad).GetValue(obj, null);
        if (valor.ToString() == ValorPropiedad.ToString())
        {
            if (idIndustria == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu informacion fue de ayuda